# Is it possible to use the term 'production capacity' in plural, i.e. 'production capacities'? If yes, in which cases?

Tags: grammatical-number

A manufacturer writes in its newsletter that it has completed a number of investment projects 'to build up its production capacities'. As far as I understand, the manufacturer would like to imply that the production capacity of each of its manufacturing site units will increase after the investment.

Would it be correct to pluralize 'production capacity' in this case?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? Have you looked for other uses of "production capacities", such as [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3439871)?

Comment: No, I don't think it's wrong. What confuses me is that the plural variant is predominantly used by non-native speakers of English (at least that's what I see on the Internet). Thank you for commenting

Comment: It's like peoples. It's odd, but that's the right word for different ethnicities. Different sites are unlikely to have a single capacity.

Comment: That seems like a reasonable interpretation, but my guess is, that's not what they meant.  I'd guess they meant "production capacity," but were a bit sloppy.  If I wanted to express what you understood, I'd say something like, "We've completed a number of investment projects to build up the production capacity at 80% of our manufacturing plants."

Comment: @aparente001: Thank you! Fully agree.

Comment: Thank you, Yosef.